# Usage of LSTM/GRU and Flatten throws dimensional incompatibility error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, multidimensional-array, keras, lstm

I want to make use of a promising NN I found at towardsdatascience for my case study.

The data shapes I have are:

```
X_train:(1200,18,15)
y_train:(1200,18,1)
```

Here the NN, which possesses among other layers GRU, Flatten and Dense.

```
def twds_model(layer1=32, layer2=32, layer3=16, dropout_rate=0.5, optimizer='Adam'
                    , learning_rate=0.001, activation='relu', loss='mse'): 
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(layer1, return_sequences=True),input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(AveragePooling1D(2))
    model.add(Conv1D(layer2, 3, activation=activation, padding='same', 
               name='extractor'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(layer3,activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=loss)
    return model

twds_model=twds_model()
print(twds_model.summary())
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
bidirectional_4 (Bidirection (None, 18, 64)            9216      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling1d_1 (Average (None, 9, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
extractor (Conv1D)           (None, 9, 32)             6176      
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 288)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 16)                4624      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 20,033
Trainable params: 20,033
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Unfortunately, I step into a kind of contradictory error trap, where input and output shapes do not match. Here the error under the upper circumstances.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [144,1] vs. [144,18,1]
     [[{{node loss_2/dense_4_loss/sub}}]]
     [[{{node loss_2/mul}}]]
```

```
Train on 10420 samples, validate on 1697 samples
Epoch 1/8

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-3f5256ff03ec> in <module>
----> 1 Test_tdws=twds_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=8, batch_size=144, verbose=2, validation_split=(0.14), shuffle=False) #callbacks=[tensorboard])

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    878           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    879           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 880           validation_steps=validation_steps)
    881 
    882   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
    327 
    328         # Get outputs.
--> 329         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    330         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    331           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3074 
   3075     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3076                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3077     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3078     return nest.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_structure,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [144,1] vs. [144,18,1]
     [[{{node loss_2/dense_4_loss/sub}}]]
     [[{{node loss_2/mul}}]]
```

And for completion the expectable error where y_train was reshaped to (1200*18,1):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-2a6d0761b794> in <module>
----> 1 Test_tdws=twds_model.fit(X_train, y_train_flat, epochs=8, batch_size=144, verbose=2, validation_split=(0.14), shuffle=False) #callbacks=[tensorboard])

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    774         steps=steps_per_epoch,
    775         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 776         shuffle=shuffle)
    777 
    778     # Prepare validation data.

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle)
   2434       # Check that all arrays have the same length.
   2435       if not self._distribution_strategy:
-> 2436         training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
   2437         if self._is_graph_network and not self.run_eagerly:
   2438           # Additional checks to avoid users mistakenly using improper loss fns.

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
    454                      'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
    455                      'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
--> 456                      'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
    457   if len(set_w) > 1:
    458     raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 12117 input samples and 218106 target samples
```

Utilized versions are:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
-                      nsorflow-gpu
-ensorflow-gpu         1.13.1
-rotobuf               3.11.3
-umpy                  1.18.1
absl-py                0.9.0
antlr4-python3-runtime 4.8
asn1crypto             1.3.0
astor                  0.7.1
astropy                3.2.1
astunparse             1.6.3
attrs                  19.3.0
audioread              2.1.8
autopep8               1.5.3
backcall               0.1.0
beautifulsoup4         4.9.0
bezier                 0.8.0
bkcharts               0.2
bleach                 3.1.4
blis                   0.2.4
bokeh                  1.1.0
boto3                  1.9.253
botocore               1.12.253
Bottleneck             1.3.2
cachetools             4.1.0
certifi                2020.4.5.1
cffi                   1.14.0
chardet                3.0.4
click                  6.7
cloudpickle            0.5.3
cmdstanpy              0.4.0
color                  0.1
colorama               0.4.3
colorcet               0.9.1
convertdate            2.2.1
copulas                0.2.5
cryptography           2.8
ctgan                  0.2.1
cycler                 0.10.0
cymem                  2.0.2
Cython                 0.29.17
dash                   0.26.0
dash-core-components   0.27.2
dash-html-components   0.11.0
dash-renderer          0.13.2
dask                   0.18.1
dataclasses            0.6
datashader             0.7.0
datashape              0.5.2
datawig                0.1.10
deap                   1.3.0
decorator              4.4.2
defusedxml             0.6.0
deltapy                0.1.1
dill                   0.2.9
distributed            1.22.1
docutils               0.14
entrypoints            0.3
ephem                  3.7.7.1
et-xmlfile             1.0.1
exrex                  0.10.5
Faker                  4.0.3
fastai                 1.0.60
fastprogress           0.2.2
fbprophet              0.6
fire                   0.3.1
Flask                  1.0.2
Flask-Compress         1.4.0
future                 0.17.1
gast                   0.3.3
geojson                2.4.1
geomet                 0.2.0.post2
google-auth            1.14.0
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
gplearn                0.4.1
graphviz               0.13.2
grpcio                 1.29.0
h5py                   2.10.0
HeapDict               1.0.0
holidays               0.10.2
holoviews              1.12.1
html2text              2018.1.9
hyperas                0.4.1
hyperopt               0.1.2
idna                   2.6
imageio                2.5.0
imbalanced-learn       0.3.3
imblearn               0.0
importlib-metadata     1.5.0
impyute                0.0.8
ipykernel              5.1.4
ipython                7.13.0
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
ipywidgets             7.5.1
itsdangerous           0.24
jdcal                  1.4
jedi                   0.16.0
Jinja2                 2.11.1
jmespath               0.9.5
joblib                 0.13.2
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         6.1.2
jupyter-console        6.0.0
jupyter-core           4.6.3
Keras                  2.2.5
Keras-Applications     1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
keras-rectified-adam   0.17.0
kiwisolver             1.2.0
korean-lunar-calendar  0.2.1
librosa                0.7.2
llvmlite               0.32.1
lml                    0.0.1
locket                 0.2.0
LunarCalendar          0.0.9
Markdown               2.6.11
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
matplotlib             3.2.1
missingpy              0.2.0
mistune                0.8.4
mkl-fft                1.0.15
mkl-random             1.1.0
mkl-service            2.3.0
mock                   4.0.2
msgpack                0.5.6
multipledispatch       0.6.0
murmurhash             1.0.2
mxnet                  1.4.1
nb-conda               2.2.1
nb-conda-kernels       2.2.3
nbconvert              5.6.1
nbformat               5.0.4
nbstripout             0.3.7
networkx               2.1
notebook               6.0.3
numba                  0.49.1
numexpr                2.7.1
numpy                  1.19.0
oauthlib               3.1.0
olefile                0.46
opencv-python          4.2.0.34
openpyxl               2.5.5
opt-einsum             3.2.1
packaging              20.3
pandas                 1.0.3
pandasvault            0.0.3
pandocfilters          1.4.2
param                  1.9.0
parso                  0.6.2
partd                  0.3.8
patsy                  0.5.1
pbr                    5.1.3
pickleshare            0.7.5
Pillow                 7.0.0
pip                    20.0.2
plac                   0.9.6
plotly                 4.7.1
plotly-express         0.4.1
preshed                2.0.1
prometheus-client      0.7.1
prompt-toolkit         3.0.4
protobuf               3.11.3
psutil                 5.4.7
py                     1.8.0
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.8
pycodestyle            2.6.0
pycparser              2.20
pyct                   0.4.5
pyensae                1.3.839
pyexcel                0.5.8
pyexcel-io             0.5.7
Pygments               2.6.1
pykalman               0.9.5
PyMeeus                0.3.7
pymongo                3.8.0
pyOpenSSL              19.1.0
pyparsing              2.4.7
pypi                   2.1
pyquickhelper          1.9.3418
pyrsistent             0.16.0
PySocks                1.7.1
pystan                 2.19.1.1
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2019.3
pyviz-comms            0.7.2
PyWavelets             0.5.2
pywin32                227
pywinpty               0.5.7
PyYAML                 5.3.1
pyzmq                  18.1.1
qtconsole              4.4.4
rdt                    0.2.1
RegscorePy             1.1
requests               2.23.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.0
resampy                0.2.2
retrying               1.3.3
rsa                    4.0
s3transfer             0.2.1
scikit-image           0.15.0
scikit-learn           0.23.2
scipy                  1.4.1
sdv                    0.3.2
seaborn                0.9.0
seasonal               0.3.1
Send2Trash             1.5.0
sentinelsat            0.12.2
setuptools             46.3.0
setuptools-git         1.2
six                    1.14.0
sklearn                0.0
sortedcontainers       2.0.4
SoundFile              0.10.3.post1
soupsieve              2.0
spacy                  2.1.8
srsly                  0.1.0
statsmodels            0.9.0
stopit                 1.1.2
sugartensor            1.0.0.2
ta                     0.5.25
tb-nightly             1.14.0a20190603
tblib                  1.3.2
tensorboard            1.13.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.6.0.post3
tensorflow-estimator   1.13.0
tensorflow-gpu         1.13.1
termcolor              1.1.0
terminado              0.8.3
testpath               0.4.4
text-unidecode         1.3
texttable              1.4.0
tf-estimator-nightly   1.14.0.dev2019060501
Theano                 1.0.4
thinc                  7.0.8
threadpoolctl          2.1.0
toml                   0.10.1
toolz                  0.10.0
torch                  1.4.0
torchvision            0.5.0
tornado                6.0.4
TPOT                   0.10.2
tqdm                   4.45.0
traitlets              4.3.3
transforms3d           0.3.1
tsaug                  0.2.1
typeguard              2.7.1
typing                 3.6.6
update-checker         0.16
urllib3                1.22
utm                    0.4.2
wasabi                 0.2.2
wcwidth                0.1.9
webencodings           0.5.1
Werkzeug               1.0.1
wheel                  0.34.2
widgetsnbextension     3.5.1
win-inet-pton          1.1.0
wincertstore           0.2
wrapt                  1.11.2
xarray                 0.10.8
xlrd                   1.1.0
yahoo-historical       0.3.2
zict                   0.1.3
zipp                   2.2.0
```

A lot of thanks in advance for every hint that points towards a running code ;-)!

### EDITEDITEDIT

After updating tensorflow and keras to the latest version, I received the error below. The error persisted, although tensorlfow, CUDA 10.1 and cudnn 8.0.2 were completely deleted and reinstalled. The error was produced both with my original and with **Fallen Aparts** example code.

```
UnknownError:    Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/bidirectional/forward_gru/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5731]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

```
None
Epoch 1/4

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-64eb8afffe02> in <module>
     27     print(twds_model.summary())
     28 
---> 29     twds_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=4)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1846                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))],
   1847         captured_inputs=self.captured_inputs,
-> 1848         cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1849 
   1850   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1926         args,

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    548               inputs=args,
    549               attrs=attrs,
--> 550               ctx=ctx)
    551         else:
    552           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~\Anaconda3\envs\Tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

UnknownError:    Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/bidirectional/forward_gru/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5731]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

The respective version list:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------------
-                        nsorflow-gpu
-ensorflow-gpu           2.3.0
-rotobuf                 3.11.3
absl-py                  0.9.0
antlr4-python3-runtime   4.8
asn1crypto               1.3.0
astor                    0.7.1
astropy                  3.2.1
astunparse               1.6.3
attrs                    19.3.0
audioread                2.1.8
autopep8                 1.5.3
backcall                 0.1.0
beautifulsoup4           4.9.0
bezier                   0.8.0
bkcharts                 0.2
bleach                   3.1.4
blis                     0.2.4
bokeh                    1.1.0
boto3                    1.9.253
botocore                 1.12.253
Bottleneck               1.3.2
cachetools               4.1.0
certifi                  2020.4.5.1
cffi                     1.14.0
chardet                  3.0.4
click                    6.7
cloudpickle              0.5.3
cmdstanpy                0.4.0
color                    0.1
colorama                 0.4.3
colorcet                 0.9.1
convertdate              2.2.1
copulas                  0.2.5
cryptography             2.8
ctgan                    0.2.1
cycler                   0.10.0
cymem                    2.0.2
Cython                   0.29.17
dash                     0.26.0
dash-core-components     0.27.2
dash-html-components     0.11.0
dash-renderer            0.13.2
dask                     0.18.1
dataclasses              0.6
datashader               0.7.0
datashape                0.5.2
datawig                  0.1.10
deap                     1.3.0
decorator                4.4.2
defusedxml               0.6.0
deltapy                  0.1.1
dill                     0.2.9
distributed              1.22.1
docutils                 0.14
entrypoints              0.3
ephem                    3.7.7.1
et-xmlfile               1.0.1
exrex                    0.10.5
Faker                    4.0.3
fastai                   1.0.60
fastprogress             0.2.2
fbprophet                0.6
fire                     0.3.1
Flask                    1.0.2
Flask-Compress           1.4.0
future                   0.17.1
gast                     0.3.3
geojson                  2.4.1
geomet                   0.2.0.post2
google-auth              1.14.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.1
google-pasta             0.2.0
gplearn                  0.4.1
graphviz                 0.13.2
grpcio                   1.29.0
h5py                     2.10.0
HeapDict                 1.0.0
holidays                 0.10.2
holoviews                1.12.1
html2text                2018.1.9
hyperas                  0.4.1
hyperopt                 0.1.2
idna                     2.6
imageio                  2.5.0
imbalanced-learn         0.3.3
imblearn                 0.0
importlib-metadata       1.5.0
impyute                  0.0.8
ipykernel                5.1.4
ipython                  7.13.0
ipython-genutils         0.2.0
ipywidgets               7.5.1
itsdangerous             0.24
jdcal                    1.4
jedi                     0.16.0
Jinja2                   2.11.1
jmespath                 0.9.5
joblib                   0.13.2
jsonschema               3.2.0
jupyter                  1.0.0
jupyter-client           6.1.2
jupyter-console          6.0.0
jupyter-core             4.6.3
Keras                    2.4.3
Keras-Applications       1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing      1.1.2
keras-rectified-adam     0.17.0
kiwisolver               1.2.0
korean-lunar-calendar    0.2.1
librosa                  0.7.2
llvmlite                 0.32.1
lml                      0.0.1
locket                   0.2.0
LunarCalendar            0.0.9
Markdown                 2.6.11
MarkupSafe               1.1.1
matplotlib               3.2.1
missingpy                0.2.0
mistune                  0.8.4
mkl-fft                  1.0.15
mkl-random               1.1.0
mkl-service              2.3.0
mock                     4.0.2
msgpack                  0.5.6
multipledispatch         0.6.0
murmurhash               1.0.2
mxnet                    1.4.1
nb-conda                 2.2.1
nb-conda-kernels         2.2.3
nbconvert                5.6.1
nbformat                 5.0.4
nbstripout               0.3.7
networkx                 2.1
notebook                 6.0.3
numba                    0.49.1
numexpr                  2.7.1
numpy                    1.18.5
oauthlib                 3.1.0
olefile                  0.46
opencv-python            4.2.0.34
openpyxl                 2.5.5
opt-einsum               3.2.1
packaging                20.3
pandas                   1.0.3
pandasvault              0.0.3
pandocfilters            1.4.2
param                    1.9.0
parso                    0.6.2
partd                    0.3.8
patsy                    0.5.1
pbr                      5.1.3
pickleshare              0.7.5
Pillow                   7.0.0
pip                      20.2.2
plac                     0.9.6
plotly                   4.7.1
plotly-express           0.4.1
preshed                  2.0.1
prometheus-client        0.7.1
prompt-toolkit           3.0.4
protobuf                 3.11.3
psutil                   5.4.7
py                       1.8.0
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycodestyle              2.6.0
pycparser                2.20
pyct                     0.4.5
pyensae                  1.3.839
pyexcel                  0.5.8
pyexcel-io               0.5.7
Pygments                 2.6.1
pykalman                 0.9.5
PyMeeus                  0.3.7
pymongo                  3.8.0
pyOpenSSL                19.1.0
pyparsing                2.4.7
pypi                     2.1
pyquickhelper            1.9.3418
pyrsistent               0.16.0
PySocks                  1.7.1
pystan                   2.19.1.1
python-dateutil          2.8.1
pytz                     2019.3
pyviz-comms              0.7.2
PyWavelets               0.5.2
pywin32                  227
pywinpty                 0.5.7
PyYAML                   5.3.1
pyzmq                    18.1.1
qtconsole                4.4.4
rdt                      0.2.1
RegscorePy               1.1
requests                 2.23.0
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
resampy                  0.2.2
retrying                 1.3.3
rsa                      4.0
s3transfer               0.2.1
scikit-image             0.15.0
scikit-learn             0.23.2
scipy                    1.4.1
sdv                      0.3.2
seaborn                  0.9.0
seasonal                 0.3.1
Send2Trash               1.5.0
sentinelsat              0.12.2
setuptools               46.3.0
setuptools-git           1.2
six                      1.14.0
sklearn                  0.0
sortedcontainers         2.0.4
SoundFile                0.10.3.post1
soupsieve                2.0
spacy                    2.1.8
srsly                    0.1.0
statsmodels              0.9.0
stopit                   1.1.2
sugartensor              1.0.0.2
ta                       0.5.25
tb-nightly               1.14.0a20190603
tblib                    1.3.2
tensorboard              2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit   1.7.0
tensorflow-gpu           2.3.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator 2.3.0
termcolor                1.1.0
terminado                0.8.3
testpath                 0.4.4
text-unidecode           1.3
texttable                1.4.0
Theano                   1.0.4
thinc                    7.0.8
threadpoolctl            2.1.0
toml                     0.10.1
toolz                    0.10.0
torch                    1.4.0
torchvision              0.5.0
tornado                  6.0.4
TPOT                     0.10.2
tqdm                     4.45.0
traitlets                4.3.3
transforms3d             0.3.1
tsaug                    0.2.1
typeguard                2.7.1
typing                   3.6.6
update-checker           0.16
urllib3                  1.22
utm                      0.4.2
wasabi                   0.2.2
wcwidth                  0.1.9
webencodings             0.5.1
Werkzeug                 1.0.1
wheel                    0.34.2
widgetsnbextension       3.5.1
win-inet-pton            1.1.0
wincertstore             0.2
wrapt                    1.11.2
xarray                   0.10.8
xlrd                     1.1.0
yahoo-historical         0.3.2
zict                     0.1.3
zipp                     2.2.0
```

Comment: What is the shape of your data? I checked it with `X_train.shape = (1200, 18, 15)` and `y_train.shape = (1200, 18, 1)` and `twds_model.fit(X_train, y_train)` works just fine.

Comment: @Fallen Apart: They are exactly those shapes. What versions of keras, tensorflow etc. do you have? Maybe this is the prob?

Comment: I have 2.2.0, but I guess the version shouldn't be the issue. Make sure one more time that you have those shapes.

Comment: The shapes are correct (s. below). There must be some version difference. However, also with 2.3.0 the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is what worked for me:

```
Tensorflow 2.3.0
Keras 2.4.2
CUDA 10.1
cuDNN 7.6.5
```

alongside with this code snippet retrieved from this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11812#issuecomment-617933020)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0' # Set to -1 if CPU should be used CPU = -1 , GPU = 0

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
cpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')

if gpus:
    try:
        # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
elif cpus:
    try:
        # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        logical_cpus= tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('CPU')
        print(len(cpus), "Physical CPU,", len(logical_cpus), "Logical CPU")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
```

A lot of thanks goes to **@Fallen Apart** who stayed with me. In case of being curious, you might also want to have a brief glimpse into my [follow up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63475694/prediction-for-multi-variate-input-lstm-or-lstm-conv1d-network-way-off-track) ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error, check if the following code works for you:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, GRU, Bidirectional, AveragePooling1D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
import numpy as np


def twds_model(layer1=32, layer2=32, layer3=16, dropout_rate=0.5, optimizer='Adam',
               learning_rate=0.001, activation='relu', loss='mse'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(layer1, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(AveragePooling1D(2))
    model.add(Conv1D(layer2, 3, activation=activation, padding='same',
                     name='extractor'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(layer3, activation=activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
    return model


if __name__ == '__main__':
    X_train = np.random.rand(1200, 18, 15)
    y_train = np.random.rand(1200, 18, 1)

    twds_model = twds_model()
    print(twds_model.summary())

    twds_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20)
```

Comment: Sry for the late answer: There was a bit of the usual version update horror, but now I am back to the upper versions.

I copy pasted your code into a fresh Jupyter Notebook:
Unfortunately, the error completely remains the same.

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,1] vs. [32,18,1]
  [[{{node loss/dense_1_loss/MeanSquaredError/sub}}]]
  [[{{node ConstantFoldingCtrl/loss/dense_1_loss/MeanSquaredError/weighted_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Switch_0}}]]

Comment: @JDS Yeah, right now it looks like cuDNN issue, I would try cuDNN v7.6.5.